# New computer, old provisioning profile but iPhone no longer works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, build, provisioning

Provisioning Profile problems, as usual.  I'll keep it brief.

I got a new laptop.  Installed XCode.  Exported the provisioning profile from my old machine and imported it to the new one. My iPhone shows up fine in the devices list, connected, attached to the correct profile.

But when I try and debug using the device, it tell me

```
No provisioned iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.
```

I've tried refreshing, re-adding, re-creating.  Its not interested.

Is there something I'm missing.  Do I need to create new certificates? Do I need to re-create a whole new profisioning profile from scratch.

Thanks for any help or advice or emotional support you can give me.

the duncs

Comment: It says I can't accept my own answer for 2 days.  Any suggestions MCannon?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, turns out there was nothing wrong with my keys or my certificates or provisioning profiles.  For what its worth, if anyone else has the same problem:

My iPhone version was 4.2, but the default setting for the iOS device to build to was 4.3.

Fixed it by setting the iOS development target to 4.2.

School boy error I'm sure, but definitely not an obvious one to work out.  An error along the lines of 'no iOS device of build version 4.3 could be found'.  But anyway. Thanks to everyone for their help and time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to export your certificates from the keychain app on the old machine and import them into the new machine's keychain. You can re-download your provisioning profiles from the provisioning center, but your certificates can't; they must be migrated.

**EDIT:** I might have muddled it up. I think it's your private keys that you have to export/import.

Comment: Done.  Still no luck.  [Thanks Marcelo - any more suggestions?]

Comment: @Duncan: Maybe it's your private keys that you have to migrate. That's about the extent of my knowledge; this stuff is a blacker-than-black art.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo.  I tried the certificates too and that didn't get me any further.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Duncan: Did you mean to say that you tried the private keys too? They are different to the certificates.

Comment: Yep.  I exported private keys and I exported certificates.

Comment: @Duncan: Then I'm sorry, but that's all I can offer. I usually poke around, download everything, import/export everything, sometimes do it all again, and eventually it just works. Someone at Apple needs to be taken out the back and given a good spanking for this stuff.

Comment: Ha!  Yep, you're right.  Its a right pain in the ass to do anything.  I'm not happy at all.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you go through that step in which the XCode collects debugging information from the device?(I presume this would happen as this version of Xcode is seeing the device for the first time).

Comment: Yep.  It collected all that information and the said 'successful'.  Thanks Vin.

Comment: what if if you do not have chance to export the certificate from the old machine??

Comment: @IlkerBaltaci: Then you'll have to go through the certificate signing process again.